# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 Ошибка Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Подскажите что не так, пожалуйста

```
public void signUpUser(User user){
        String insert = "INSERT INTO " + Const.USERS_TABLE + "(" +
                Const.USERS_FIRSTNAME + "," + Const.USERS_LASTNAME + "," +
                Const.USERS_USERNAME + "," + Const.USERS_PASS + "," +
                Const.USERS_LOCATION + Const.USERS_STATUS + ")" +
                "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getFirstname());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getLastname());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getUsername());
            preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getPass());
            preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getLocation());
            preparedStatement.setString(6, user.getStatus());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: запятых 4, а вопросов 6. После LOCATION нужно запятую вставить

Comment: Большое спасибо